# Does the "Sync Locally?" option in Ubuntu One, mean that it just uploads to the server?

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-one

I'm currently running Ubuntu 11.04 Beta 1 and was looking at the Ubuntu One client. There is an option to "Sync locally?" for my cloud folders. So, I'm wondering if this means that if it's not ticked then the folder is uploaded to the cloud server, but if I make changes somewhere else it won't be merged with the documents on this computer. Or, does it mean that the folder won't be uploaded to my Ubuntu One at all?

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means the folder exists “in the cloud”, and if the option to sync locally is checked, then changes to the folder and its contents (new files, editions, deletions, etc) will be synced with that: that is, that changes elsewhere will be brought down to this computer, and that changes on this computer will be pushed up. Conversely, if the option is *not* selected, then local changes  will not by uploaded, and remote changes will not be downloaded.